# SSIS New Column with Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have Created one new column using Derived column Record_Type as (DT_WSTR,25)"" data type, Then I used another derived column to create my condition  for Record_Type is  PRDCT_IND ==  TRUE  ? "PRIME" : "SEC".

Can it be possible to create both the thing in one derived column?

Appreciate your help.

343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to create a column with a conditional as the data that is defined as a DT_WSTR,25, so you could create it all in one step with the following:

(DT_WSTR,25)(PRDCT_IND == TRUE ? "PRIME" : "SEC")

first set of () casts the entire result to a DT_WSTR of length 25
second set of () uses the value of PRDCT_IND to set the value to either "PRIME" or "SEC"

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You have been here a few months now, you should take this time to go back through your questions and mark any helpful answers to them as accepted.  You can do this by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer and turning it green.  People will be more likely to help you in the future if you do this!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no.
You can't use the columns created in a component within the same component.

You'll have to add a second derived column component.